# Understanding Docker best practice and running webservers

Tags: docker

I am in the situation of running a simple PHP7.0, Redis and NGINX server in a single container.

This means I run `php7.0-fpm` *and* `ngxinx` *and* `redis` as a service.

But in the best practices I am reading:

```
# Run only one process per container
In almost all cases, you should only run a single process in a single container.
Decoupling applications into multiple containers makes it much easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers.
If that service depends on another service, make use of container linking.
```

Does this mean that it would be best to run one container with PHP7.0 and the application and another with nginx and another with redis?

Comment: Yes, this is the recommendation. Take a look at Docker Compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/) - this is usually used to start one container per application. You can link the containers through Compose's `link` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nwinkler in comments is right, the recommendation is for good. Couple of advantages of decoupling applications into multiple containers are:

1. **Build time**

It is true that docker does hash check and does not build the layers of the image if no changes happened but this is limited to layers structure (if layer X changes all layers above X will be built). This means it will start getting painful when your images start getting bigger.

2. **Containers are isolated**

When you are attached to your `ngxinx` you are pretty sure that any changes you are doing is not going to cause changes in your `php` container and that's always a good practice.

3. **Scalability**

You need ten more `Redis`, good, let's run ten more `Redis` containers.

In general I would go for a dockerfile for a base image for any scenario and in your case one which is whatever all the three containers of yours (`php`, `redis` & `nxginx`) share (thirdparty libs, tools etc). Then three dockerfiles for building each image. Then a `bash` or `docker-compose.yml` script for running the images inside containers.

Comment: Swarm would do. Bash script should almost work. Which ever preferred.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with Bash in this context. Can you please explain?

Comment: I guess if one would not want to go with Docker Swarm, can automate and customize the management of containers and launching them via written bash script. If many containers are to be used maybe Swarm is more convenient.